# Actionlink rowindex stored to a C# get set

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ActionLink that is deleting a row from a html table and should be updating the controller. The problem however is that the information of the row that the button is on isn't being shared with the controller once the button is clicked.

```
<table id="LansingData" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>Row ID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Records)
            {                
            <tr id="@item.RowIndex">



                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.RowIndex }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?');", @class = "delete-button" })</td>
                <td>@item.RowIndex</td>
            </tr>
             }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is my controller that is performing the delete.

```
public ActionResult Delete(int? rowID)
        {
            if (rowID == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            LansingMileage lansing = db.LansingMileages.Find(rowID);
            if (lansing == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(lansing);
        }

        //POST:
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
        [OnAction(ButtonName = "Delete")]
        //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Delete(int rowID)
        {
            LansingMileage lansing = db.LansingMileages.Find(rowID);
            db.LansingMileages.Remove(lansing);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

The desired result will be for the link to post to the controller with the rowID of the whatever link was selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a naming issue. The parameter is called `id` in the view and (most likely) in route definition, but the controller expects `rowID`. Just rename this last one to be `id` too:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
```

Model binding in MVC is done by name, so make sure posted parameters always match those expected on the server side.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that I misnamed it.